# Using the FileSystem provider

Tags: powershell

I need to use the FileSystem provider and using an appropriate cmdlet, create a zero-lenght file name C:\Zero.txt.  I know I need to use New-Item within it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I used at the PS D:\> prompt

Comment: new-item -path c:\ -name zero.txt -type file    it created it and now I am trying to change the name of the file to TESTING and can't formulate the syntax

Comment: Please add those to proper code blocks in your question.

Comment: PS D:\> new-item -path c:\name zero.txt -type file

Comment: This is how I entered the command, but don't understand what you mean by proper code blocks.  I'm very new to PowerShell so please excuse me if the question sounds strange.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I need to do using the FileSystem provider and using the appropriate cmdlet, create a zero-lenght file named c:\Zero.txt (use New-Item)  Then I need to see if I can change the contents of C:\zero.txt to TESTING and if I get an error, why?

Comment: Is this homework, by any chance?

Comment: Yes.  However I think I solved it on my own.  I need to change the contents of the file to TESTING using Set-Item, but I believe that is not possible since Set-Item is used for variables or registry keys.

Comment: You're using an important keyword in your comment there... 'change the ***content***s of the file'

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the question, especially since you've effectively already answered it yourself in the comments.

In order to create a empty file (zero length) with the name zero.txt, you can use the command:

```
New-Item -Path C:\ -Name zero.txt -Type File
```

You mentioned wanting to rename it in the comments, to do which you can use `Rename-Item`:

```
Rename-Item -Path C:\zero.txt -NewName TESTING
```

Of course, you can skip the rename by just creating the file with the desired name right away:

```
New-Item -Path C:\ -Name TESTING -Type File
```